# Difference of installation on openSUSE KDE and Gnome

Tags: linux, opensuse-12.2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are there two different ways of installation in openSUSE KDE and openSUSE Gnome](https://superuser.com/questions/519257/are-there-two-different-ways-of-installation-in-opensuse-kde-and-opensuse-gnome)

Hi I have recently installed openSUSE on my system(switched from RHEL 6). When I was installing the system I was asked to choose between KDE and GNome and I chose KDE. After the installation I've found that support for openSUSE is very minimum. Is there a difference between the way to install stuff in openSUSE KDE and openSUSE Gnome. Because on a few forums I have opens up a new tab and some config file opens. http://software.opensuse.org/package/cairo-dock