# Are there two different ways of installation in openSUSE KDE and openSUSE Gnome

Tags: opensuse

I have recently installed openSUSE on my machine. I am unable to install packages easily on this OS as there is not much help online for this OS. And I have seen on a few forums that people say if you are using KDE version you will need a source file as well. Now what does that mean. Is rpm file not sufficient when using KDE version because I am using KDE version only. And also downloading repo's in YaST and installing is not that convenient as much as the OS claims it is.

Comment: Don't cross post please. Questions can always be migrated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What are the difficulties you are experiencing with YaST? If the package you need is in the repository, you can install it using the command line utility `zypper`.

```
sudo zypper search package_name
sudo zypper install package_name
```

Comment: No but YaST installs packages that are not even neccessary like why does it need Library Office to run Dropbox. So I decided to install from Terminal, and whats the significance of source file, like in this link "http://software.opensuse.org/package/cairo-dock" when you click 12.2 it opens up 3-options, 32-bit, 64-bit and source, why do people keep saying that source is an important file in KDE. When I click on it, another rpm file is downloaded, what is the difference between 64-bit rpm and source rpm?

Comment: What package you want to install?